# Magento 2 - Create New Theme based on the blank theme

Tags: magento2, theme

I'm new to Magento
I try to create a new theme based on the Magento blank theme
and I follow the Frontend developer guide in Magento web site but I could not inherit from Magento/blank and when I open the site it wants to load the CSS and javascript

### I create these folders and files

```
TestVender/
└── TestTheme
    ├── etc
    ├── media
    │   └── TestPreview.jpg
    ├── registration.php
    ├── theme.xml
    └── web
        ├── css
        ├── images
        └── js
```

---

### and theme.xml

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
     <title>Test Theme</title> <!-- your theme's name -->
     <parent>Magento/blank</parent> <!-- the parent theme, in case your theme inherits from an existing theme -->
     <media>
         <preview_image>media/TestPreview.jpg</preview_image> <!-- the path to your theme's preview image -->
     </media>
 </theme>
```

---

### and registration.php

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/TestVender/TestTheme',
    __DIR__
);
```

---

and I add this to
\var\www\html\magento\dev\tools\grunt\configs\themes.js

---

```
themename: {
        area: 'frontend',
        name: 'TestVender/TestTheme',
        locale: 'en_US',
        files: [
            'css/styles-m',
            'css/styles-l'
        ],
        dsl: 'less'
    },
```

---

could anyone help me to solve the problem?

and this is how my page look like when I open it

[image]

Comment: what is the problem you are facing? It's not clear to me

Comment: The Theme want load the css and javascript it seam to be it did not inherit from magento/blank

Answer (score 5):

To apply a custom theme please follow below steps

**Create a theme directory**

To create the directory for your theme:

1. Go to `<your Magento install dir>/app/design/frontend`.
2. Create a new directory named according to your vendor name:
   `/app/design/frontend/<Vendor>`.
3. Under the `vendor` directory, create a directory named according to
   your theme. (e.g. mytheme)

   in theme directory structure looks like this

> ```
> app/design/frontend/
> ├── <Vendor>/ (my)
> │   │   ├──...<theme>/  (themename)
> │   │   │   ├── ...etc
> │   │   │   ├── ...media
> │   │   │   ├── ...web
> |   |   |   |    ├── ...css
> |   |   |   |    ├── ...images
> |   |   |   |    ├── ...js
> │   │   │   ├── registration.php
> │   │   │   ├── theme.xml
> ```

**Declare your theme**

Add or copy from an existing `theme.xml` to your theme directory

app/design/frontend//

Configure it using the following example:

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
     <title>blank</title> <!-- your theme's name -->
     <parent>Magento/blank</parent> <!-- the parent theme, in case your theme inherits from an existing theme -->
     <media>
         <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image> <!-- the path to your theme's preview image -->
     </media>
 </theme>
```

**Register your theme**

in your theme directory add a ***registration.php*** file with the following content:

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>',
    __DIR__
);
```

---

Where `<Vendor>` is your vendor name, `<theme>` is the theme code.

**Configure Your theme**

```
<your Magento install dir>dev\tools\grunt\configs\themes.js

    themename: {
        area: 'frontend',
        name: 'my/themename',
        locale: 'en_US',
        files: [
            'css/styles-m',
            'css/styles-l'
        ],
        dsl: 'less'
    },
```

flush your cache
apply your theme from admin Store > configuration >   design

Comment: Thanks guys for your help I did all of that and I have the same porblem

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the following commands in order to create symlinks for css and js files of your theme. After that these files should start loading on frontend:

First delete the current static theme files, if any, in order to apply newly added changes:
`grunt clean:<theme-name>`
This will remove all `pub/static/frontend` files of theme

To Republish symlinks to the source files to the `pub/static/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/<locale>` directory.

`grunt exec:<theme-name>`

To Compile.css files using the symlinks published in the `pub/static/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/<locale>` directory

`grunt less:<theme-name>`

Now clear `var/cache`,`var/page_cache` and then check.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help 
but when I run grunt clean:Theme I get this message
-----------------------------------------------

/var/www/html/magento/dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js:56
    TestTheme: {
    ^^^^^^^^^
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
Warning: Task "clean:TestTheme" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

-----------------------------------------------

Comment: are u able to run other commands ? if clean isn't working, then simply go to pub/static/frontnend/<Vendor> folder and delete your theme's folder from there if it exists. then proceed with rest of the commands

Comment: Hi Reena Parekh 
Thank you for your time 
I found out the couse of the problem was 
this code in dev\tools\grunt\configs\themes.js file
----------------------------------
TestTheme: {
        area: 'frontend',
        name: 'TestVender/TestTheme',
        locale: 'en_US',
        files: [
            'css/styles-m',
            'css/styles-l'
        ],
        dsl: 'less'
    },*/
----------------------------------

Comment: when delete it the grunt clean:TestTheme work but I get different error 
-------------
Running "clean:TestTheme" (clean) task
Verifying property clean.TestTheme exists in config...ERROR
>> Unable to process task.
Warning: Required config property "clean.TestTheme" missing. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2016-01-05 05:14:14 UTC)
loading tasks                156ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 95%
loading grunt-contrib-clean    3ms  ▇▇ 2%
clean:TestTheme                5ms  ▇▇▇ 3%
Total 165ms
------------------

Comment: do you know why I get this error

Comment: this might help - https://github.com/firstandthird/load-grunt-config/issues/40

Comment: I fix the problem with grunt it work fine but the main problem still if I chose the custom theme (TestTheme) no css or javascript are load  to the web page

Comment: did u clear var/cache, var/generation and var/page_cache ?

Comment: yes I did clear the cache in var/cache and var/page_cache but in var/generation there is no folder with my theme name (TestTheme)

Comment: just clear var generation. no need to search for ur folder name there

Comment: in the generation there are three folder : ( Composer,  Magento,  Symfony ) should I delete them or not

Comment: and every time i did this command ( grunt clean: TestTheme
grunt exec: TestTheme
grunt less: TestTheme) and have to do this php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy or not even the defult theme will load

Answer (score 0):

Create your `theme.xml` as -

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
     <title>blank</title>
     <parent>Magento/blank</parent>
     <media>
         <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image> 
     </media>
 </theme>
```

And after that copy folders `Magento_Theme` and `web` form `blank` to `your theme`.

Answer (score 0):

After create and change theme you need to run following command in order to generate static css,js etc files

```
bin/magento  setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

Register your theme in below path

dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js

Like I did for my porto theme,

porto: {
        area: 'frontend',
        name: 'Smartwave/porto',
        locale: 'en_US',
        files: [
            'css/styles-m',
            'css/styles-l'
        ],
        dsl: 'less'
    },

Answer (score -1):

Locate into theme table of your database, find your theme name by `theme_title` column and change its type to `0` as physical theme type.