# Magento 2 custom Theme no css and products loaded in frontend

Tags: magento2, theme, static-content

I created a new Template based on the Blanco/Luma theme as pointed out in several howto's [as in this topic)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95995/magento-2-create-new-theme-based-on-the-blank-theme)

Strange thing is that the css and the products (and images) which are available do not load in frontend. So I end up with just plain text. 
I tried all solutions mentioned like deleting the static files, running php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy and made sure the permission on the files are ok.

This is how my frontend html looks like:

```
<code>
!doctype html>
<html lang="nl-NL">
    <head >
        <script>
    var require = {
        "baseUrl": "http://site1/pub/static/frontend/MyTemplate/menes1-theme/nl_NL"
    };
</script>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta name="description" content="Default Description"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="Magento, Varien, E-commerce"/>
<meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<title>Home page</title>
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="http://site1/pub/static/frontend/MyTemplate/menes1-theme/nl_NL/mage/calendar.css" />
<link  rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://site1/pub/static/frontend/MyTemplate/menes1-theme/nl_NL/Magento_Theme/favicon.ico" />
<link  rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://site1/pub/static/frontend/MyTemplate/menes1-theme/nl_NL/Magento_Theme/favicon.ico" />
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="http://site1/pub/static/frontend/MyTemplate/menes1-theme/nl_NL/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="http://site1/pub/static/frontend/MyTemplate/menes1-theme/nl_NL/mage/requirejs/mixins.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="http://site1/pub/static/_requirejs/frontend/MyTemplate/menes1-theme/nl_NL/requirejs-config.js"></script>
            </head>
    <body data-container="body" data-mage-init='{"loaderAjax": {}, "loader": { "icon": "http://site1/pub/static/frontend/MyTemplate/menes1-theme/nl_NL/images/loader-2.gif"}}' class="cms-home cms-index-index page-layout-1column">
</code>
```

So it looks like all the files are available in the static folder? Why are they not loaded? 
When using the Luma theme, the products and css are loaded without any problem? I have all the files in place for the template to work (as in the sample mentioned). Only thing I did not get form that sample was where the mentioned config has to go? In all other howto's I found there was no config mentioned so maybe that might be the problem? I do not have Grunt running on my server. Since the final production server on a hosted environment does not has that available.

Any hints on how to get this right? Magento version is 2.09

Comment: Ok made some progress. I emptied the cache which was kept by the server rm -R /tmp/magento/var/cache/* That made at least my BE working again and also showed me some new errors on the front end.
<code>

Comment: Ok made some progress. I emptied the cache which was kept by the server rm -R /tmp/magento/var/cache/* That made at least my BE working again and also showed me some new errors on the front end.

<code>Notice: getimagesize(): Read error! in /var/www/www.site1/www/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Image.php on line 949</code>
But looking at that file (Image.php) it is not there? Only Cache.php ?

Comment: Had a look in the log files and it says:

[2016-09-19 13:35:03] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_adminhtml_STORE2_331b80c99f1d265b3f83441bdff2abf85: Please correct the XML data and t$
[2016-09-19 13:35:03] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'global_notices' element cannot be added as child to 'global.notices', because the latter doesn't$
[2016-09-19 13:35:03] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'logo' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist

So what does that mean? It can't find some parts? What xml file is referred to?

Comment: Anyone who can help sorting out this error?

Saw that there was already a post about this in 2015. Which was closed, with the result that it was solved in newer version of Magento 2.0. But apparently it is still there? 
Strange thing is though that I do not have any error when loading the Luma or Blanco Template. Than products are shown as well as the images! 
So where to look for this strange behaviour?

Comment: To be sure I did not mess things up, I will start over again and create a new theme from scratch. Will it help copying over the /vendor/magento/theme-fronted-luma and use that as my base for creating a new frontend-theme?

Comment: Surprisingly that worked out very well! 
So there might have been a mistake in one of the files pulled in for the custom template :) Or my assumption that in the <vendor><my_template> dir, only will go the files needed for the templates config and the files which will override the "base" template file in case you like to make changes (css, view.xml, etc) is wrong? 
Now saying that, can I leave out the "luma-template" files/ dirs which I do not want to adapt for my template? Please advise!

Answer (score 0):

Please add your css file in the page.xml of the 
**App/design/frontend/yourtheme/default/layout/page.xml**
add the css file as follow,

**`<`action method="addCss"`><`stylesheet`>`css/yourfilename.css`<`/stylesheet`><`/action`>`**

CSS file should located to the 
**skin/frontend/yourtheme/default/css/**

Comment: I think that applies to Magento 1.9 isn't it. In Magento 2.* There is no Dir skin/frontend ....