# Magento 2 - Images gone after swapping Theme to custom theme

Tags: magento2, mamp

I've installed Magento 2 with Data and it all installed well and all data and images where there.

I then created a theme based on Luma and as soon as I activated the new theme all the images have disappeared.

How can I bring the images back?

Comment: What files do you currently have in your custom theme? Is this something you created from scratch? Could you share some more details of the theme itself to pin down what might be causing the problem. It is common for a typo in the `etc/view.xml` to cause this kind of error.

Comment: It's basically a clone of LUMA. I copied Vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma and then added that to app...directory. Everything works except that all images are gone

Comment: I don't have a certain answer, so i'm just making a comment here, but try removing the etc folder and see if things show back up. Then each folder after that. Also, this could be a compilation issue,  so as you remove folders make sure to clear the cache and recompile as you don't want to remove the right folder and not have the change show up in the compiled code.

Comment: Which etc folder location?

Comment: `app/design/frontend/{{vendor_namespace}}/{{theme}}/etc/view.xml`. This file has a ton for frontend site configs in it and can wreck all kinds of havoc on your site.

Comment: OK, I've stripped my whole custome theme for just 2 files .. registration.php and theme.xml, nothing else. For some reason the data is still gone :(  What can it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have created correct File & Folder Structure. Please follow

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

Please Inspect & Check for Image Path/URL & refer [Magento 2 - Create New Theme based on the blank theme](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95995/magento-2-create-new-theme-based-on-the-blank-theme)

[Magento 2 - Create New Theme based on the blank theme](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95995/magento-2-create-new-theme-based-on-the-blank-theme)

[magento2: how can i deploy my theme only](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101131/magento2-how-can-i-deploy-my-theme-only)